# Existence of non-singular point

Tags: algebraic-geometry

What is the most direct way of showing the existence of a non-singular point on an affine variety ? The only method I'm aware of is to show that affine variety is birational to a hypersurface and then use the Jacobian criterion.

Without appealing to hypersurface case then we can show for an affine variety generated by ideal $\mathfrak{a} = \langle F_1, \ldots, F_n \rangle$ that

$$rk_{k(x)}\left(\frac{\partial F_i}{\partial X_j}(x) \right) \leq rk_{k(X)}\left(\overline{\frac{\partial F_i}{\partial X_j}}\right) = n - \dim X$$

with equality iff (x) is non-singular point. Let $G_p(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ denote the $(n-d)$-minors of the jacobian matrix and $g_p \in k[X]$ the corresponding elements of the coordinate ring. Then the set of singular points is

$$ \bigcap_{p} V(g_p) $$

This is clearly closed subset, but to show it's proper, one needs to show at least one of $V(g_p)$ is proper, which is equivalent to $g_p \notin k[X]^\star$.

**Question**: Is there a way to show this without appealing to hypersurface case ?

**edit**: Implicitly $k[X]$ is reduced so it's actually enough to show that $g_p$ is non-zero (not a non-unit). This follows from the second equality (which ultimately relies on theory of differentials).

Comment: Sure, there are other ways, but this is the most direct if you don't have so much technology. One way which avoids the hypersurface case is via differentials - would you be up for an answer using that language? (Also, minor correction, $V(g_p)$ proper is equivalent to one of $g_p$ non-nilpotent, not one of $g_p$ non-unit.)

Comment: yes I would be interested thank you. (I think I was implicitly assuming coordinate ring is reduced)

Comment: it occurs to me your comment finalises the solution, as not all $g_p$ are zero